# Get all parent documents in a mongoDB model tree structure

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I'm using a model tree structure for my collection. As references I'm using parent-fields. I need to get attributes from the current object and all its parents. The last element in a path has a field 'target'. So I start with

```
var result = parent = Articles.findOne({target: this.params._id});

do {
    parent = Articles.findOne({_id: parent.parent}).parent;
    for (var attrname in parent) { result[attrname] = parent[attrname]; }
}
while (parent.parent === null);
```

That seems to be very inefficient to me. Isn't it possible to do that with one line to get an object with all elements? Then I could process that object.

**Example documents**

```
{
    "_id" : "LD6h5ZcDuJjexfKfx",
    "title" : "title",
    "publisher" : "public",
    "author" : "author"
}
{
    "_id" : "KSiyh8zHRq8RZQ2E6",
    "edition" : "edition",
    "year" : "2020",
    "parent" : "LD6h5ZcDuJjexfKfx"
}
{
    "_id" : "5yCk4y25wrLBLZhyY",
    "pageNumbers" : "1-10",
    "target" : "9sjhzPhyTuQ5Kbh6v",
    "parent" : "KSiyh8zHRq8RZQ2E6"
}
```

So starting with `"target" : "9sjhzPhyTuQ5Kbh6v"` I would like to get the two parent documents (in this example).

At least I need the dataset

```
"title" : "title",
"publisher" : "public",
"author" : "author",
"edition" : "edition",
"year" : "2020",
"pageNumbers" : "1-10"
```

Comment: how is your full document looks like?

Comment: Updated the post with an example.

Comment: this can help https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in a single query then you need to follow the [array of ancestors](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/model-tree-structures/#model-tree-structures-with-an-array-of-ancestors) pattern in Mongodb. Otherwise you need to recursively traverse the branches above the leaf node as you are doing. For hierarchies with low depth such as yours this is not a big penalty.

With an array of ancestors your doc tree would look like:

```
{
    "_id" : "LD6h5ZcDuJjexfKfx",
    "title" : "title",
    "publisher" : "public",
    "author" : "author",
}
{
    "_id" : "KSiyh8zHRq8RZQ2E6",
    "edition" : "edition",
    "year" : "2020",
    "ancestors" : ["LD6h5ZcDuJjexfKfx"],
    "parent" : "LD6h5ZcDuJjexfKfx"
}
{
    "_id" : "5yCk4y25wrLBLZhyY",
    "pageNumbers" : "1-10",
    "target" : "9sjhzPhyTuQ5Kbh6v",
    "ancestors" : ["LD6h5ZcDuJjexfKfx","KSiyh8zHRq8RZQ2E6"],
    "parent" : "KSiyh8zHRq8RZQ2E6"
}
```

To get the doc and its parents:

```
Articles.find({ $or: [ { target: target },
  _id: { $in: Articles.findOne({ target: target }).ancestors }]});
```

Comment: I'm just thinking because I want to treat comments for an article in that way. That means there can be 3-4 levels deep with i.e. 10 comments. That means there are 40 DB query taks for one article. For me it sounds bad.

Comment: Then the array of ancestors could be a better choice.

Comment: could you please show me in the example what I have to change?

Comment: See changes in answer

Comment: I don't need ancestors and parents?

Comment: And how would my query be - to get the comlete dataset?

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know how many level deep the docs are. So findOne().ancestors.ancestors is not dynamic...

Comment: Every leaf contains all ancestors above it, depth doesn't matter.

Comment: Is the second `).ancestors` a mistake? The currect query has a syntax error, but I don't see where...